# Why is $N_u=DN_{\phi(u,v)}(\phi_u)$?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm having some trouble understanding the following:

In the differential geometry book I'm reading, the author argues the following:

> Let $S$ be an orientable surface with orientation $N:S\to \mathbb S^2$. Then for all $p\in S$, the tangent planes $T_pS$ and $T_{N(p)}\mathbb S^2$ are the same, thus $$DN_p:T_pS\to T_pS$$ is an endomorphism. Let let $\phi(u,v)$ be a parametrization in $S$ and let $N(u,v)=N\circ\phi(u,v)$

Now this is the part that I don't understand:

> Then, we have that $N_u=DN_{\phi(u,v)}(\phi_u)$ and $N_v=DN_{\phi(u,v)}(\phi_v)$

I don't understand why this equality would be true. Why is this the case?
By the way, my only contact with differential geometry was through this book, so If this notation isn't the one commonly used, let me know.

Note:
Here the derivative $DN_p$ is defined as follows:

> Let $f:S_1\to S_2$ be a function between two smooth surfaces. Then the derivative of $f$ in $p\in S_1$ is defined as the linear map $Df_p:T_pS_1\to T_{f(p)}S_2$ such that $Df_p(\alpha'(0)) =(f\circ \alpha)'(0)$, for any curve $\alpha$ with $\alpha(0)=p.$

Comment: The confusion is that they’re using $N$ for two different functions. Write $\bar N = N\circ\phi$. Then the chain rule gives precisely $\bar N_u = (N\circ\phi)_u = DN_{\phi(u,v)}(\phi_u)$.

Comment: But why is $(N\circ \phi)_u=DN_{\phi(u,v)}(\phi_u)$? That's the part I don't get. Here $DN_{\phi(u,v)}$ is not the total derivative of $N$, but instead the derivative of a function between two smooth surfaces. How do these two relate to each other? @TedShifrin

Comment: Added the definition I'm considering for $DN_p$ in the post @TedShifrin

Comment: Let $\alpha(t) = \phi(u+t,v)$. Then $\alpha’(0) = \phi_u(u,v)$.

Comment: You might consider $N$ not as a function on the surface but as a function on the chart (a fuinction of $u,v)$. $dN={\partial N\over \partial u} du+{\partial N\over \partial v} dv= N_udu+N_vdv$ is perhaps more intuitive ?